# How to add picture column in OpportunityLineItem in SelectSearch page

Tags: opportunity-lineitem, images

I want to add a picture detail into OpportunityLineItem. I created a formula field with IMAGE but my page doesn't render the picture.

[image]

The message is "Image Added by User...".

Some of you've added images in this page?

Comment: is your Formula field a TEXT field return type. Please paste your formula in your question

Comment: IMAGE(PricebookEntry.Product2.Image_Url__c ,'',200,200) . Where Image_Url__c contains the entire URL if the image, also I added the image repository on my remote sites. Thanks!